# Drupal , something wrong with ajax popup forms, how to fix?

Tags: ajax, drupal, colorbox

I have site with Drupal 7, Colorbox and Webform modules. I use it like it

```
<a class="colorbox-node" href="/node/25?width=600&height=400">Call me</a>
```

The problem is, when my form popped up i see error message: "This form could not be submitted because $_POST was truncated to 115 input vars. PHP max_input_vars is 3000 and needs to be increased." I tried to make it - 10000, but no success. And one more i have another site on that hosting, with the same logic but no problem there. What should i check?

Screenshot - http://take.ms/OkaEa

Regards,
Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem with the Modal forms (with ctools) module as well. I upgraded to the latest dev version of Webform (Feb 19, 2015) and that resolved the issue. This item from the issue queue discusses the cause and fix included that release:

https://www.drupal.org/node/2417757

Comment: You are the winner! Thank you, dev version solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of colorbox are you using? Please note, from https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox:

> Form support in Colorbox is removed in 7.x-2.x

Use Modal forms (with ctools) instead or one of the other modules that has this feature, there are a number of them.

The attempt to support opening various forms in a Colorbox was in hindsight never a good idea. Form error handling and form redirects are complicated, a lot of code would be needed to do it correctly.

If you absolutely want to continue using the form support you need to stay with 7.x-1.x.

Comment: I tried both. The problem appears in colorbox and modal forms too. I use last versions from repo.